# NullPointerExcception when C# calling Fortran function returning derived type

Tags: c#, fortran, dllimport, fortran-iso-c-binding

I'm calling a Fortran DLL from a C# program. I manage to pass a Fortran derived type as an argument, but when calling a function that returns a derived type as return value I get a NullPointerException.

I suspect I'm doing something wrong in the C# side DLLImport.

Fortran library:

```
module FortranCallBack
USE ISO_C_BINDING
IMPLICIT NONE

TYPE, BIND(C) :: FOO
   INTEGER :: A, B
END TYPE

CONTAINS

SUBROUTINE Test(myFoo) BIND(C)
   !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: Test

   TYPE(FOO), INTENT(IN) :: myFoo
   write (*,*) "Foo: ", myFoo%A, " ", myFoo%B
END SUBROUTINE

FUNCTION FuncTest() BIND(C) RESULT(RES)
   !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: FuncTest
   TYPE(FOO) :: RES
   RES = FOO(42, 13)
END FUNCTION
```

and the C# code calling it:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public class FOO 
    { 
        public int a; 
        public int b; 
    }


    class Program {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var f = new FOO { a = 1, b = 2 };
            // This works
            Test(f);

            // Here I get NullPointerException...
            FOO myFoo = FuncTest();
        }

        [DllImport("fortran_lib.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "test")]
        public static extern void Test( [In] FOO foo );

        [DllImport("fortran_lib.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "functest")]
        public static extern FOO FuncTest();
    }
}
```

The code is compiled with Intel Fortran 10.1 and .NET framework 4.0

Comment: The way a structure is returned as a function result is not well standardized, the pinvoke marshaller assumes the Microsoft way.  All you can do is remove the [MarshalAs] attribute (it is definitely not LPStruct) and try again.  And it ought to be Test(ref FOO foo), otherwise the safe way.

Comment: I tried with removing the LPStruct, but I'm still getting the same null pointer exception in the latter call.

Comment: Always use tag [tag:fortran] and only add the version when necessary to distinguish that your question is specific. For example that you cannot use Fortran 2008 but only Fortran 90.